# Let $\theta_a: S_3 \to S_3$ be the function given by $\theta_a(g) = aga^{-1}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $a \in S_3$ and $\theta_a: S_3 \to S_3$ be the function given by $\theta_a(g) = aga^{-1}.$ Show that these define 6 different isomorphisms of $S_3.$

I know from the conjugation of permutation that $\sigma(1 2 3 ... n)\sigma^{-1} = (\sigma(1)\sigma(2)\sigma(3)...\sigma(n)).$ I also know  there are 6 elements in S3, which are e,(1 2),(1 3),(2 3),(1 2 3) and (1 3 2). (1 2 3)=(1 3)(1 2). But I really don't know how to prove this statement.

Comment: Can you write out the elements of $S_3$ for us, and the rules for multiplying them? (THere are many ways to do this, and it'll help us to know which one you're using). You can edit by clicking "edit' just below your question. Also: when $a$ is the identity element of $S_3$, can you tell me what $\theta_a$ is? That, too, will help us know how much you understand. Finally, can you say what it means for two isomorphisms to be "different"?

Comment: @JohnHughes Thanks for your comment! I write out the elements of S3
S3  and the rules for multiplying them. I am also uncertain about what does "different" mean. I think it means I input the same element, the output is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tsemo's answer may be suitable for you when you've studied a bit more group theory; my impression is that as of now, it's not something you're quite ready for, so I'll take a more basic approach. First, I'm going to use $a$ to denote $(1~2~3)$, so that I don't have to keep writing out permutations, and $b$ to denote $(1~2)$. I'll use $e$ for the identity permutation. It's not too hard to check that
$$
a^3 = b^2 = e
$$
and a little checking shows that 
$$
a b = ba^2
$$ (unless I've gotten it backwards and $ba = a^2b$, in which case I should have written $a = (3 ~ 2 ~ 1)$.)

Now let's look at $\theta_e, \theta_a, \theta_{a^2}$, and so on. I'll start out by showing that $\theta_e$ is different from $\theta_a$. How? I'll find an element $g$ with the property that 
$$
\theta_a(g) \ne \theta_e(g)
$$
for as you observed, two functions on $S_3$ are equal only if they take the same value on every element of $S_3$.

I'm going to look at $g = b$, so let's look at 
$$
\theta_e(b) = e b e^{-1} = e b e = b.
$$
Now what's $\theta_a(b)?$ well, because $a^3 = e$ we see that $a \cdot a^2 = e$, so $a^{-1} = a^2$. So 
$$
\theta_a(b) = a b a^{-1} = a b a^2 = a (ab)
$$
where that last equality comes from the $ba^2  = ab$ that I wrote above. That further simplifies to $\theta_a(b) = a^2b$, which is different from $b$, so $\theta_e$ and $\theta_a$ are different.

You can now do the same thing for each of the other $\theta_u$, for each element $u$ of the group $S_3$. You need to find something to show that each of these is different from all the others that you've encountered. Probably making a table of values will be your best bet.

Best of luck, and when you're done, you'll see why Tsemo's compact answer is so very useful as a way of avoiding drudgery. :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It is really helpful. I know σ(123...n)σ−1=(σ(1)σ(2)σ(3)...σ(n)). (σ(1)σ(2)σ(3)...σ(n)) must be different for each σ in S3, right? If that's true, I am finished, right?

Comment: If you really **know** that's true (it may or may not be...I haven't checked!) then your conclusion is also correct, for the very reason you give.

Comment: OK. I'm pretty sure that it's *not* true. For the permutations I gave above, $bab^{1} = bab = a^2 b b = a^2$, which is not the same as $b$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Show that $\theta_{aa'}=\theta_a\circ\theta_{a'}$, it is a morphism of groups. Then remark that $\theta_a=Id$ implies that $a$ is an element of the center of $S_3$, since the center of $S_3$ is the neutral element, deduce that $\theta$ is injective.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! How do you know θa=Id?

Comment: I don't know that $\theta_a=Id$, suppose that $\theta_a=Id$, this implies that $a$ is in the center and $a$ is the neutral element of $S_3$, since the center of $S_3$ is its neutral element.